# $\frac{4}{13}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$ solve for positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Solve for positive integers $x,y,z$

$$\frac{4}{13}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

I tried to solve it by some generel work but it didn't help.